# Javascript stopwatch with millisecond increments

Tags: javascript, stopwatch

I am trying to put together a stopwatch using JavaScript. I have got the date to populate with the correct information but my Stopwatch doesn't work. I click start and the numbers never move from 0, I would like to have it increment in MS no seconds. I have my code for the JS and the HTML also. HTML is functioning as it should but the JS is not. I am very green to the JavaScript world and i have looked and looked and was unable to come across a solution that would be a benefit to me. Thanks for your assistance.

```
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

var stopwatchTimer;

var elapsedMinutes = 0;

var elapsedSeconds = 0;

var elapsedMilliseconds = 0;

var displayCurrentTime = function() {

  var now = new Date();

var hours = now.getHours();

var ampm = "AM";
if (hours > 12) { 

hours = hours - 12;

ampm = "PM";


} else { 

 switch (hours) {

case 12:

 ampm = "PM";

break;

case 0:  

 hours = 12;

ampm = "AM";

 }

 }


$("hours").firstChild.nodeValue = hours;

$("minutes").firstChild.nodeValue = padSingleDigit(now.getMinutes());

$("seconds").firstChild.nodeValue = padSingleDigit(now.getSeconds());

$("ampm").firstChild.nodeValue = ampm;

};

var padSingleDigit = function(num) {

if (num < 10) { return "0" + num; }

else { return num; }

};

var tickStopwatch = function() {    
// I also need to increment in 10 milliseconds increments but unsure if I //have this right


var ms=0;
var sec=0;
var min=0;

var frame= function() {
If(ms==1000)
        ms=0;
        sec++;
}
if(sec==60) {
        sec=0;
        min++;

document.getElementById("s_seconds").innerHTML = valueOf(sec);
document.getElementById("s_minutes").innerHTML = valueOf(min);
document.getElementById("s_ms").innerHTML = valueOf(ms);
}

};

var startStopwatch = function(evt) {

};

var stopStopwatch = function(evt) {

};

var resetStopwatch = function(evt) {

};
window.onload = function() {    

displayCurrentTime();    
setInterval(tickStopwatch, 1000);
};
"use strict"; //evt is in a separate file
var evt = {
    attach: function(node, eventName, func) {

    },
    detach: function(node, eventName, func) {

    },
    preventDefault: function(e) {

    }
};


    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html> 
    <head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <title>Clock</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="clock.css"> 

    <script src="library_event.js"></script> 

    <script src="clock.js"></script> 

    </head> 
    <body> 
    <main> 
    <h1>Digital clock with stopwatch</h1> 
    <fieldset> 
    <legend>Clock</legend> 
    <span id="hours">&nbsp;</span>: 
    <span id="minutes">&nbsp;</span>: 
    <span id="seconds">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp; 
    <span id="ampm">&nbsp;</span> 
    </fieldset> 

    <fieldset> 
    <legend>Stop Watch</legend> 
    <a href="#" id="start">Start</a>&nbsp; 

    <a href="#" id="stop">Stop</a>&nbsp; 

    <a href="#" id="reset">Reset</a>&nbsp; 

    <span id="s_minutes">00</span>: 
    <span id="s_seconds">00</span>: 
    <span id="s_ms">000</span> 
    </fieldset> 
    </main> 
    </body> 
    </html>
```

Answer (score 7):

If you incrementally update the values `ms`, `seconds`, `minutes` you'll never be accurate. You'll lose time with every update. There simply is no interval that can operate at that speed and accuracy in JS.

Instead, compute them from the internal clock

```js
let offset = 0,
  paused = true;

render();
  
function startStopwatch(evt) {
  if (paused) {
    paused = false;
    offset -= Date.now();
    render();
  }
}

function stopStopwatch(evt) {
  if (!paused) {
    paused = true;
    offset += Date.now();
  }
}

function resetStopwatch(evt) {
  if (paused) {
    offset = 0;
    render();
  } else {
    offset = -Date.now();
  }
}

function format(value, scale, modulo, padding) {
  value = Math.floor(value / scale) % modulo;
  return value.toString().padStart(padding, 0);
}

function render() {
  var value = paused ? offset : Date.now() + offset;

  document.querySelector('#s_ms').textContent = format(value, 1, 1000, 3);
  document.querySelector('#s_seconds').textContent = format(value, 1000, 60, 2);
  document.querySelector('#s_minutes').textContent = format(value, 60000, 60, 2);
  
  if(!paused) {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Stop Watch</legend>
  <a href="#" id="start" onclick="startStopwatch()">Start</a>&nbsp;

  <a href="#" id="stop" onclick="stopStopwatch()">Stop</a>&nbsp;

  <a href="#" id="reset" onclick="resetStopwatch()">Reset</a>&nbsp;

  <span id="s_minutes">00</span>:
  <span id="s_seconds">00</span>:
  <span id="s_ms">000</span>
</fieldset>
```

`offset` stores two values: when `paused` it stores the value at which you stopped, otherwise it stores the offset you have to add to `Date.now()` to compute the value.

The value is the time in ms, computing seconds and minutes out of it is basic arithmetic.

Comment: @marc_s, Thank you

Comment: Nice code, though there is a problem (depending on the application). When stopStopwatch is called, the offset is properly set, but then it typically takes a tiny amount of time before the next rendering takes place, due to the requestAnimationFrame(render). Thus the time shown after that rendering is slightly later. This must be handled properly if this is used for accurate timings.

Comment: @Magnus *"Thus the time shown after that rendering is slightly later."* No, not on stop. Only while the stopwatch is running and that on purpose. 
If your first render occurs 2 seconds after you clicked on start it will show you 2 seconds and not pretend you've just started. `render()` always shows the correct value *at the time it is called* whether you use requestanimationFrame or setInterval(..., 1000). The correct timing of the stopwatch is independent of the renderer. And if you need even more precision, you can replace the underlying clock: `Date.now()` to `performance.now()`

Comment: You are right, sorry, mistake on my part!

Answer (score 0):

Your interval function is set to run once per 1000ms (or 1 sec), which won't give you 1ms resolution.  In fact, the best you can do is 10ms resolution with `setInterval`.  You also need to increment a counter, which you currently don't do.

Try:

```
setInterval(tickStopwatch, 10);

var ms = 0;
var tickStopwatch = function() {    
   var ms += 10;
   // rest of your logic
}
```

Comment: `setInterval` does not support a 1ms resolution. minimum is 10ms.